# onload and window.onload not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jquery-ui, onload

I am working on a project that are able to run in both Chrome and IE.My problem is after I change some part of the code to open the modal dialog using jQuery UI, the b.jsp cannot use  in IE and Chrome, so I try to change it to window.onload. It works for Chrome but not for IE.In the console,it return "Not implemented". I have 2 jsp file, **a.jsp** file is the parent page and **b.jsp** file is the pop up modal dialog.

In my **b.jsp** ,

```
<html>
    <head>
          //some script here
    </head>
    <body onload = "getData();" >
           <form name="form1">
            //form table here
           </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Function **getData()** are from **a.jsp**,

```
function getData(){

    var materialDesc = document.getElementById("materialDesc").value;
    if(materialDesc== "materialDesc[1]"){
        alert("No record");
        var materialDesc = '';

        $("#openModalDialog").dialog("close");

 }else{
        for(var i=0; i< materialDesc.length;i++)
         {
             document.all.detail_desc.options[i] = new Option(materialDisplay[i]);
             document.all.detail_desc.options[i].value = materialDesc[i];

         }
    }   
}
```

The message error:

[image]

Where is my mistake? I was thinking that the error is cause by the function. Thank you.

Comment: document.all????

Comment: @epascarello - that's an antiquated property that still exists today

Comment: Yes and when I coded with it in 1998 it was okay to use.

Comment: `In the console,it return "Not implemented"` what does? where does this message come from? can you get more detail about this "message"?

Comment: `<form name:"form1">` ??? interesting (made up) syntax

Comment: change `function getData(){ consoloe.log('works'); }` - if you get "works" in the console, then the issue is *nothing to do with onload*

Comment: @epascarello sorry but is it wrong if I use it? I am new in javascript . I am actually changing the existed code only so I don't know much about the method they use to get the value other than document.getElementById.

Comment: It is a very out dated way to access the DOM and not all of the browsers implement it.

Comment: @JaromandaX ah sorry its typo

Comment: well you have document.getElementById, document.querySelector, and a lot more ways to reference an element.

Comment: surely that's not stopping `onload` from firing

Comment: That is probably something else and hard to tell from the code

Comment: @JaromandaX I already include screenshot of the error message

Comment: I did try to change the function as Jaromanda suggest but it does not work

Comment: Which version of IE? Are you loading the page using http or https? Do you happen to have IE in some "compatibility" mode with an earlier version of IE? Do you have to support IE at all?

Comment: @JaromandaX Version 11. Using http . Im not sure, how to check? I am not using my laptop actually. Yes that's my task's objective,to run on both Chrome and IE.

Comment: check the compatibility view settings or the emulation mode in the developer tools